# Shell scripting: Way to parse parameters from command line

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, parsing, parameters

```
myscript [-a a-arg] [-c c-arg] [-b] [-e] somedirectory
```

Given that I want my shell script be invoked at the command line using the above parameters - where [these brackets] denote that they are optional - what is the best method to parse them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few methods to parse command line arguments. Assuming you're using bash, the least painful way is probably using [`getopts`](http://aplawrence.com/Unix/getopts.html).

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts  "abc:" flag
do
  echo "$flag" $OPTIND $OPTARG
done
```

```
[~]$./ssc.sh -ab -c file
a 1
b 2
c 4 file
```

Comment: @John T. Thanks for the answer: solve all except for the last bit: my `somedirectory` is not an option - how would I get the last parameter (after `getopts` finishes looping)?

Comment: It will be the last option left in `$@` I believe.

Comment: Got it - `shift $(($OPTIND - 1))` was what I was after!

Comment: Excellent! Happy scripting :)